# Django - remove primary_key=True from an existing model?

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I have a table that I've already migrated into the MySQL database and one of the fields has `primary_key = True`. I realized this needs to be different and I need to remove the `primary_key = True`. I'd like Django to create its own auto incrementing primary key fields (like it does with all models if you don't specify a primary_key).

If I simply remove the `primary_key = True`, Django complains because it can't auto-assign an auto-increment value to its new `id` field (which is now the primary key field).

What's the best way to change this one field to *not* have `primary_key = True`? This particular model doesn't have any records yet in the database, so I think I'm in a better position than if I had records in there. I'm not sure if I should just drop the table and migrate as if it's a brand new table or if I need to take some other approach?

**Edit**

What I actually tried:

`python manage makemigrations accounting`

*The model in question is called `Invoice` and I'm wanting to change the field `inv_num` to not be the primary key*

Django asks:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to invoice without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

So I select option 1, and type `1`.

Django creates the migration file, so I do:

`python manage migrate accounting`

And Django complains with:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'id'")`

My research indicates that this is because you can't auto-assign a value to a primary key field.

**Edit 2**

The Model in question:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
  inv_num = models.CharField(max_length = 144, primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Invoice Number')
  brokerage = models.ForeignKey(Brokerage, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Brokerage')
  lot = models.ForeignKey(Lot, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = "Lot")
  vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Bill To (Vendor)')
  contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Bill To (Contact)')
  due_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Date')
  fund = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
  org_amt = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0, verbose_name = 'Original Amount of Invoice')
  amtos = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0, verbose_name = 'Amount OS')
  is_fine = models.BooleanField(default = False)
  is_reversed = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = 'Has Been Reversed')
  is_paid = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = 'Is Paid')
  is_locked = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = 'Is Locked')
  is_archived = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = 'Is Archvied')
  org_je = models.CharField(max_length = 144, blank = True, null =True, verbose_name = 'Original JE')
```

There are a number of other models in this Django App that have `Invoice` as a foreign key. But those too don't have any data in them in the database.

I wonder if I should just drop the whole app from the database, and re-migrate it in? I do have a bunch of other apps that have data I cannot simply drop though.

Comment: Can you post what actually you tried and what did Django complain?
Also if there are no records then just drop the table and re-migrate. No harm

Comment: I was considering droping the table and re-migrating. Wouldn't this be problematic if there are other tables that point to this table via foreign keys? Again, those tables shouldn't have any records in them either. And if I did that, wouldn't I have to wipe out all the migration history from the database pertaining to this specific model?

Comment: No, as far as all tables are empty and you don't want to save the state of relationships and structures of your table, simply drop and re-migrate. You dont have to worry about clearing migration history either if you are certain that you do not have to rollback to those, and your models are good enough to create new tables for you

Comment: But I feel like I've dropped a table in the past (not this one) and tried to re-migrate but django complained that there were already migrations in the database. I've had to delete those rows from the migration_history table which referenced the table I had dropped. Only then was I able migrate a "new" table (really a copy of the old table but with changes). But you're saying that's not going to happen?

Comment: @MohitC You said "as far as all tables are empty" -- but that's not the case here. Only this specific model has no records. There are *lots* of other tables with a lot of data that I cannot drop.

Comment: Please post your model class for this table